# How to make jenkins kill a script when the job is stopped?

Tags: ssh, jenkins

I recently moved a Jenkins job to a new machine, and now whenever I manually kill a job it leaves the script it started (over ssh) running, despite the session having ended.  It seems that jenkins is spawning a child process, or something along those lines.

Any ideas on why this behavior changed, and how to fix it?